# jQuery dataTables sorting is not working for (mm/dd/yyyy) format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my project I want to sort date which is in `dd-mm-yyyy format`. I tried like this below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        $('#myTable').dataTable( {
          "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
          "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]], 
          "pageLength": 100 
        });
    });
</script>
```

But this is not working. Here only date and month is getting sorted not also on the basis of year.

```
<?php echo date('m/d/y', strtotime($project->post_date)); ?>
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Please show a minimum of effort by searching your title before asking

Comment: Can you show the code that renders a row in your table?